# Quantity Button with RadioGroup To Calculate Subtotal Price

Tags: android, android-studio, mobile, switch-statement, price

Hello I have been struggling to figure out how to get the subtotal with my quantity increment and decrement buttons for subtotal.

What I want is after the customers chooses a type the price will show on the bottom.
Then if they would like multiple orders they can press the + button and the  price will change as well depending if they increase or decrease. Here is the Code

MainActivity

```
public class expresso_item1 extends AppCompatActivity  {

private Spinner spinner;

RadioGroup radioGroup;
RadioButton radioButton;
TextView textView;


TextView value;
int count = 0;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_expresso_item1);

    value = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.quantity1);
    radioGroup = findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
    textView = findViewById(R.id.total1);



}

public void RButton (View v){
    int radioID = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
    switch(radioID){
        case R.id.type1:
            textView.setText("$"+"5");
            break;
        case R.id.type2:
            textView.setText("$"+"10");
            break;
        case R.id.type3:
            textView.setText("$"+"12");
            break;
    }


}

public void plus (View v){
    count++;
    value.setText("" + count);
}

public void minus (View v){
    if (count <= 0 ) count = 0;
    else count--;
    value.setText("" + count);
}

}
```

Currently only shows the type price the customer wants. Any help is appreciated!

Here is a pic of the Design Layout:
[Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLj5l.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead

Initialize another global variable to get the current price below the count

```
int count = 0
int currentPrice = 0
```

Then in the **RButton()** set the new value for the currentPrice

```
public void RButton (View v){
    int radioID = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
    switch(radioID){
        case R.id.type1:
            textView.setText("$"+"5");
            currentPrice = 5
            break;
        case R.id.type2:
            textView.setText("$"+"10");
            currentPrice = 10
            break;
        case R.id.type3:
            textView.setText("$"+"12");
            currentPrice = 15
            break;
    }


}
```

Then in the **plus** and **minus** function

```
public void plus (View v){
    count++;
    value.setText("" + String.valueOf(count * currentPrice));
}

public void minus (View v){
    if (count <= 0 ) count = 0;
    else count--;
    value.setText("" + String.valueOf(count * currentPrice));
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you! The explanation was very thorough. Will definitely try this.

Comment: Hello! happen to come across an error. with the .toString() in the function. It says it cannot resolve method. I have already tried invalidate cache and restart

Comment: @Ivor I've edited the answer, sorry i use the wrong method to convert int to String, the toString() function only use in Kotlin

Comment: Ahh I see thank you for the fix! Sorry for the hassle im not familiar with Kotlin methods to fix it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

this is how I would have done,
make a global variable quantity (instead of count) and initialise with value 0.

I will set this to quantity textview, it will increase whenever user presses on + image button and similarly decrease on -.

I will also make another variable rate initialise it to 0.

```
//global variable
private val quantity = 0
. 
. 
. 
quantityTexview.text = 
quantity.toString() 
val rate = 0
//it's value will change depending on 
//selected radio button ($5, $10,$12) 
subtotal.text = quantity * rate 
//set this to subtotal textview 
subtotalTextview.text = 
subtotal.toString()
```

Comment: Change val to var..